# How to use the blame feature in TFS?

Tags: tfs

How do you use the blame feature in TFS?

Comment: easy, pick another dev and let rip!

Comment: For those who haven't run into "blame" as a formal source control feature, it is used in SVN, CVS, maybe other tools. Basically, it displays who changed the offending line of code, and when. Metaphorically speaking, it puts the crosshairs on someone's back.

Comment: 'Annotate' is a better name for it than 'blame' - you're not typically looking to point the finger at someone so much as who can help you understand it. Both tools also show the revision/changeset where the alteration was made, which really helps understand why code was written that way.

Comment: Don't forget svn praise.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

The TFS equivalent is the Annotate command I believe. (Simply right click on the versioned file in the source code explorer and select "Annotate".)

There's more information on this over on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385979.aspx).

Comment: Too bad TFS has "annotate this version" instead of "annotate previous version" as in SVN when tracing a line of code over multiple changes.

Comment: @MatthijsWessels, I agree there's not built in feature for this.  You can however view history, individually annotate each changeset into it's own window then split the view across those annotations.  http://ge.tt/7og5eKW1/v/0?c

Comment: @Adam How I usually used blame was when I saw a line of code and wanted to know who added it and why. I would do blame, I could see who edited the line last, but maybe that change was just a trivial change like spacing. Being able to easily do "blame previous version" repeatedly, I could track the line to when the real change I care about was made. So I don't necessarily need to compare different blame windows, I just need to easily move to the next one that touched that line. On large files with many unrelated changes, using the View History approach costs a lot of effort.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  The only way I could find and retrieve the deleted file was by the web TFS interface.  I could not make this work in VS.  I don't know if the problem is due to VS 2005 project that I feel into my lap.

Comment: There is a "blame previous version" feature, it's just not located in the same spot as "blame current".  When you're viewing history for a file, right-click on the row for a revision and choose the "Annotate" menu item from there.

Answer (score 22):

Are you talking about the [annotate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385979.aspx) feature?